# Is there a gadget that would convert the stereo speaker output into Bluetooth?

Tags: conversion, signal

I have an old car stereo radio but the car only has a mono speaker. I do not want to do any metal cutting to install new stereo speakers. Thus, is it possible to use the output signal (low impedance) to the speakers and convert it to a Bluetooth signal so I can use a portable Bluetooth speaker?

Answer (score 1):

A DI-box would do the job, for example [most of these](http://www.behringer.com/EN/Category/Signal-Processors.aspx?s=H900) would. Look in the specs if it supports speaker output (usually the maximum wattage is specified).

Note that most of them are mono, so look for a stereo version or hook up two of them parallel.
Also look at the voltage (if it is an active one), you need 12V for most cars.

Most DI-box's have balanced output, so you would either have to connect the cold tip to GND or leave it unconnected (the manual of the specific DI-box should tell which is best).

Offcourse you would need a [bluetooth interface](http://www.belkin.com/us/F8Z492-Belkin/p/P-F8Z492/) behind it to connect to your bluetooth speakers.